# Spring authentication performed twice, first succeeds and then fails

Tags: spring, session, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to wrap my head around Spring Security framework, and implement authentication using custom `AuthenticationProvider`

When I navigate to secured url and form login with correct credentials, two login attempts are made. First succeeds and second fails, and browser stays at login page without error message.

Here is my security configuration.

```
package training2;

{ imports... }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myProvider")
    private AuthenticationProvider provider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {

            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                System.out.println("loadUserByUsername");

                return new UserDetails() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1044116648365271684L;

                    public boolean isEnabled() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }

                    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }

                    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }

                    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return true;
                    }

                    public String getUsername() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return username;
                    }

                    public String getPassword() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return "asdf";
                    }

                    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("myProvider")
    public AuthenticationProvider myProvider(final UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        return new AuthenticationProvider() {

            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return true;
            }

            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                System.out.println("authenticate");

                UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
                if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(authentication.getCredentials())) {
                    System.out.println("authentication ok");
                    return authentication;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("authentication failed");
                    throw new AuthenticationException(null) {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1022654748424786317L;
                    };
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And following is printed out in the console, when attempting to login with valid credentials

```
authenticate
loadUserByUsername
authentication ok
authenticate
loadUserByUsername
authentication failed
```

When attempting to login with invalid credentials (password anything other than *asdf*), authentication is performed only once, and fails as it should.

Why is the authentication performed twice on form login, first succeeding and then failing? Is something misconfigured, or am I missing some bean? Also, should I manage the `SecurityContext` manually, when using custom `AuthenticationProvider` implementation, or does Spring still manages it and where?

I'm also confused, why I have to explicitly annotate `userDetailsService` method as a `@Bean` to make is Spring managed, even though `WebSecurityConfigurer` declares this method.

Comment: Did you have any other code that changed the `authentication`? I can explain why twice, but don't know why second time is failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

So it will check whether the authentication is authenticated in `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, but the authentication returned in your provider is not authenticated, `FilterSecurityInterceptor` will do `authenticate` again.

```
if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(authentication.getCredentials())) {
    System.out.println("authentication ok");
    // should authenticated authenticaiton
    //return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
}
```

Comment: By setting the setAuthenticated true, following exception was thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead. Problem was solved by returning new UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationToken, but I don't understand the logic. Why authentication needs authenticated flag anyway, and why was the exception thrown?

Comment: Yes, you should new a authenticated authentication. because the old authentication contains the credentials information.

Comment: The authentication is `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in your project, `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` override the `setAuthenticated ` method, and throws an exception.